# ajax post serialized form and model list to controller method

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, post

I need to post view form, list of strings and list of objects to controller method.

My controller method looks like this

```java
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-client-policies", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getClientPolicies(@ModelAttribute("claimRegistrationForm") ClaimRegistrationForm claimRegistrationForm,
                                      @ModelAttribute("healthCardsList") List<String> healthCardsList,
                                      @ModelAttribute("bankAccountsList") List<CustomerBankAccounts> bankAccountsList,
                                      Map<String, Object> model) {

    return new ModelAndView("claims/reg/_form", model);
}
```

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: BASEHREF + 'ajax/claim-registration/get-client-policies,
    data: 'claimRegistrationForm=' + $('#claim_reg_form').serialize()
        + '&healthCardsList=' + $.parseJSON($('#healthCardsList').val())
        + '&bankAccountsList=' + $('#bankAccountsList').val(),
    success: function (response) {},
    error: function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {}
});
```

The question i have is how to i post **bankAccountList** parameter.

BankAccountList is stringified using

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Pojomatic.toString(this);
}
```

and stored in form in hidden input field

```html
<input type="hidden" id="bankAccountsList" th:value="${bank_accounts}" />
```

The value of **$('#bankAccountsList').val()** is

```
"[CustomerBankAccount{bankCode: 1, bankAccountNo: 2, bankName: {name1}},
CustomerBankAccount{bankCode: 2, bankAccountNo: 3, bankName: {name2}}]"
```

After ajax post i'm getting

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface

Answer (score 0):

Add the annotation `@RequestBody` which says that the parameter is bound to the body of the HTTP request.

Comment: I've tried that. However our application does not support RequestBody? Some configuring might be in order. I was getting exceptions that it was not allowed, and I've failed to find a solution on how to make it work.